# Why can't I directly invoke the result of apply-partially?

Tags: elisp, functions, apply

I'm confused about return value of `apply-partially`. Documentation states that it returns a function, and source of the function shows that it actually retruns a lambda. But I can't invoke the return value directly, only via `funcall`. Creating lambda directly at the call place allows me to invoke it directly.

Here are three examples of what am I talking about:

```
((apply-partially 'string-prefix-p ".") ".emacs")
;; => (invalid-function (apply-partially 'string-prefix-p "."))
((lambda (x) (string-prefix-p "." x)) ".emacs")
;; => t
(funcall (apply-partially 'string-prefix-p ".") ".emacs")
;; => t
```

Why is it working in such way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((lambda ...) ...)` is a special case, and IIRC the *only* such special case.

Lots of elisp functions return functions, and `apply-partially` is no different to any of the others in this regard.

> source of the function shows that it actually returns a lambda

Most functions are (ultimately) lambdas.  See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)What Is a Function` for details.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Function Indirection` might also be of interest.

Comment: I've rejected the following as an edit to the answer because it's not what the question was about; but in case anyone else arrives at this Q&A with this same requirement, another user wished to point out that you can define a function like so `(defalias 'dot-prefix-p (apply-partially 'string-prefix-p "."))` which can be called like this `(dot-prefix-p ".emacs")`.